# fullPage.js scrollSectionDown auto cycle

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I am using fullPage.js to create a full screen slider. 
The slider should auto cycle through sections, I am using the following code:

```
var idInterval;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],
            sectionsColor: ['#8FB98B', 'green', '#EAE1C0', '#333333', '#AA4321'],
            slidesNavigation: true,
            loopBottom: true,


            afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index) {
                if (index == 1) {
                    idInterval = setInterval(function () {
                        $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
                    }, 1500);
                }
            if (index == 5) {
                    clearInterval(idInterval);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

When reaching the fifth slide the slider stops and does not cycle on. If I do not clear the interval the slider does not work properly. I have followed the same code as I would use when auto cycling with moveSlideRight(); but it somehow does not work the same with moveSectionDown.

View the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2dhkR/254/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you don't need a `setInterval`. 
You need a `setTimeout` in this case. It makes no sense to start an interval every time you reach the 1st section.

As `afterLoad` is called once any section loads, just use that.

```
afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
    },1500);
}
```

[Demo online](http://jsfiddle.net/2dhkR/260/)